# How to set environment variable KEY_SEND with persistence in Aerospike?

Tags: aerospike

https://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/aql/settings.html

The documentation says -

> The setting values set using aql are valid only for the current
>   session. A new invoking of aql would have the default values.

So, following aql will last only for a session -

```
SET KEY_SEND TRUE
```

But, how to make persisting changes?

Basically, we want to make sure PKs are returned when fetch is done via application.

Comment: AQL doesn't have that currently. But you're saying "when fetch is done via application". AQL is not intended for you to build applications over it. If you're developing an app in Java, C, Python, etc, you have the ability to set these policies from your code.

Comment: Ok, understood that. I just want to ensure that my application configs in our production environment, which are already setup, are already taking care of that. As per my observations on our sandbox environment, where I added a new set, I had to set this config via AQL, and only after that my Java application was able to read that. Does it mean my application config did not have this set? So AQL was setting it for the application as well?

Comment: No, AQL is a client in itself (happens to be built over the C client). It cannot affect the environment of another client, unless you changed the server configuration with it. For saving the key, this can be modified operation by operation - you can have AQL send the key with the writes for 10 records, then change it and write the next 5 records without saving the keys. In a Java client you can also control this through the write policy. Reading all 15 records the Java client will get the app's key for the first 10 and not for the next 5.

Comment: @RonenBotzer I have summarized my understandings and asked a few questions in this blog http://rebellytechosaurus.blogspot.in/2018/05/clearing-confusions-related-to-keysend.html. Please see if you could answer my queries. Thanks.

Comment: Nice blog post. I'll get to it, just a but loaded with EE work at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, will wait for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

aql is a command line tool and not intended to build applications.

There is a plethora of high performing Aerospike Client (python, Java, C, etc).

Please see:

https://www.aerospike.com/download/client/

And Send Key with Java client example:

https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-java/blob/master/examples/src/com/aerospike/examples/StoreKey.java

And for python client here is some info on the key_send policy:

https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/aerospike.html#aerospike.POLICY_KEY_SEND

That said, you could set the KEY_SEND or TIMEOUT when making the command call and pass the options as a semicolon separated list.

```
 aql -c "set key_send true;INSERT INTO test.demo (PK, foo, bar) VALUES ('key1', 123, 'abc');select * from test"
set key_send true
KEY_SEND = true
INSERT INTO test.demo (PK, foo, bar) VALUES ('key1', 123, 'abc')
OK, 1 record affected.

select * from test
+--------+-----+-------+
| PK     | foo | bar   |
+--------+-----+-------+
| "key1" | 123 | "abc" |
+--------+-----+-------+
1 row in set (0.380 secs)
```

This would also work using the aql **-f option** and passing a file with both options and command

Comment: Ok, looks like this is the one for Java -
 https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/policy/Policy.html#sendKey. Will have to try that. I don't see a demo usage of the same.

Comment: Here is the example for Java: https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-java/blob/master/examples/src/com/aerospike/examples/StoreKey.java

Comment: I have summarized my understandings and asked a few questions in this blog http://rebellytechosaurus.blogspot.in/2018/05/clearing-confusions-related-to-keysend.html. Please see if you could answer my queries. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to enable key_send? Depending on use case you could use secondary indexes or scans, or batch reads.